# How to properly use scripts in an individual View in an ASP.NET MVC Core project

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In our `ASP.NET Core MVC` app in `VS2015` we have following vertical `Bootstrap` menu with a submenu on item 2. If the submenu is expanded and user clicks on any main menu item 1, item 3, or item 4, we want the submenu (of item 2) to collapse. This functionality is working fine if we use the external libraries but is not working if we use the `VS2015's built-in default libraries (that are downloaded/configured when you create a project using default ASP.NET Core MVC template). It seems either we're not properly using script in an individual view or are missing something else here.

**Question**: How can we make the following code work in `VS2015` (**Note**: Please see the next example that works with external libraries. You can verify it by copying/pasting the next example on a notepad and save it as `.html` file).

**View in VS2015** (where clicking on item 1, 3 or 4 does not collapse submenu of item 2 if that submeu was expanded):

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu" class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="false">Link 2 (toggle)</a>
                    <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function initMenu() {
            $('#menu ul').hide();
            $('#menu > li > a').on('click', function () {
                $('#menu ul').slideUp();
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            });
        }
        $(document).ready(initMenu);
    </script>
}
```

**The above behavior in the following standalone html file works**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu" class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="btn-1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1" aria-expanded="false">Link 2 (toggle)</a>
      <ul class="nav collapse" id="submenu1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1">
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>    
</body>
</html>
<script>
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide(); 
    $('#menu > li > a').on('click', function() {
        $('#menu ul').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
}
$(document).ready(initMenu);
</script>
```

**UPDATE**:

a) The above View (inside `VS2015`) displays correctly including it's submenu. The only issue is the one described above. Moreover, some other views in our project are using `@section scripts` and the javascripts in those views are workin fine. Per `@Win`'s request, following is the `_layout.cshtml` view.

b) I placed `alert('TEST')` inside the `.on('click', function() {...}` in both standalone html file and the ASP.NET `View` above; and noticed that when you click on an item of the menu in standalone html file the alert popups up but it does not happen in ASP.NET `View` above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody();
    </div>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("css", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it working without the `@section scripts` tag?

Comment: Could you show the rendered output (html) of code that run in VS2015, and also _layout.cshtml?

Comment: @Win I just added an **UPDATE** section.

Comment: Why do you then even bring in `@section` stuff into it? Both of the provided HTML use different version of the js libraries (i.e. jQuery 3.x vs 2.2), how do you even expect it to work equally? What actually **prevents** you form updating the script (and bower dependencies if not already done) references in the cshtml to a newer version?

Comment: @Tseng I just upgraded Bootstrap from `3.3.6` to `3.3.7`, jquery from `2.2.3` to `3.2.1`. Cleared the cache on the browser, ran `Clean Solution`.  But the issue remains the same.

Comment: @nurdyguy With or without the `@section scripts` it has exactly same behavior.